# Catching Magento one-page checkout redirect

Tags: javascript, magento

I’ve added a step at the end of the Magento one page checkout process. After the user hits “Place Order”, this step appears.

I’ve disabled the `$result['success'] = true;` so it shouldn’t redirect, but something (after a pause) redirects to checkout/cart and I can’t figure out what JS function is responsible.

Edit: It is possible it’s being redirected to checkout/onepage/success, but that’s bouncing it back because I’ve disabled too much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a event observer for event **'checkout_onepage_controller_success_action'** and add whatever logic you want in there.

In case you happen to be unfamiliar, here is a tutorial of how to add a event observer: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method